# Which version of PhantomJS is compatible with yslow?

Tags: phantomjs, yslow

I am stuck at this point where I see yslow is no more going for PhantomJS 2.0 as `phantom.args` property in API is deprecated. But in earlier version it works.

Please let me know which version of PhantomJS works with yslow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`phantom.args` is deprecated](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/property/args.html) from PhantomJS 2.0 onwards. Either use an older version (not recommended) or edit your yslow script to use [`system.args`](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html) instead. Note that the system module must be required.

`system.args[0]` is always the script name and `system.args[1]` is the first, but before `phantom.args[0]` was the first argument. So you will also need to change all the indexes by one.

PhantomJS had a major overhault with version 2 which also included a much newer version of WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

One has to change yslow.js at line 22.

I made changes like this

```
//args = phantom.args,
args = require('system'),
```

<strike>And it worked perfectly... This should be patched to yslow then!!!</strike>

It will get you off from the error but the arguments are not falling on right place yet.

I then changed to

```
//args = phantom.args,
system = require('system'),
args = system.args,
len = args.length,
```

But still no good sign!!!

---

Okay this is working quite fine but yet not confirmed it is stable and working great. I changed the index now to the below

```
line 69: for (i = 1; i < len; i += 1) {
```

and also changed phantom.args to args[0] just to have proper --help output description. But still i am in doubt whether it is correctly indexing now or not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `args = require('system').args`?

Comment: Ah, it rid off the error but not picking up the arguments properly, i changed it to | system = require('system'), args = system.args,    len = args.length, but still it is not working as it suppose to be.

Comment: Note that the indexing is different. I'll add that to my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer, do let me know in case you find something more to add up in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [there is a fix](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/pull/150/commits/a5ec94d4702b3b2bae92b54d2ed2e32efdc7e109) for this problem but it has not been merged yet in the main branch.